# Why do Trello archived cards show closed = False

Tags: rest, api, archive, trello

I'm using Trello REST API and I want to distinguish open cards from archived cards. However, all my cards are showing "closed = false" when pulled via the API even though if I look on my actual board, some clearly say "archived" and are stored in the archived cards. How come I can't that info accurately via API?

Answer (score 0):

When boards and lists are archived the cards they contain are **not** also archived; the open cards will remain to have `closed: false`.

To differentiate the state of cards within an archived board or list you can query for [cards as a nested resource](https://developers.trello.com/v1.0/reference#cards-nested-resource) and include the parameter only `cards=visible` (only returns cards in lists that are not closed) or `cards=open` (only return cards that are open in lists that have been archived).